# Inserting template code below code in Handlebars layout.hbs

Tags: javascript, express, tags, handlebars.js, region

I am working with an Express Handlebars project and have a template `foo.hbs` and it has some javascript I want to insert below the script tags in `layout.hbs`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    {{{body}}}
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <!-- INSERT custom code here -->
  </body>
</html>
```

So if `foo.hbs` was this:

```
<p>Hello World</p>
<!-- Want to insert this below script tags in layout.hbs -->
<script>
    // Some script that requires jQuery
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a helper for adding css/js files.

1. Create a file. Call it `helpers.js` with the following [content](https://gist.github.com/swarajgiri/60aa19bb2a168afa7f90).
2. While creating the handlebar instance, attach the above helper.

   `exphbs.create({
      extname      :'hbs',
      defaultLayout: 'layout',
      helpers      : require('PATH-TO/helpers'),
   });`
3. In `layout.hbs`, render the tags by adding `{{{renderJS js}}}` before `</body>`
4. Attach route based js files to view data.

   `res.render('/foo', {
      'js': ['/path/to/1st-custom-js.js', 'path/to/2nd-custom-js.js']
    });`